# Matlab plot a base map under a 3D volume rendering result

Tags: matlab, 3d

I use function `pcolor3` to draw a volume rendering result like the following one.
And I want to plot a base map:

[image]

The question is I can do the two images separately. But when I combine them together, both of them are missing:

[image]

Can anyone help me find a solution? Thanks.

Sorry for not attaching the code. Here it is.

```
#data is a 3d matrix. S is a shapefile.
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(xgr,ygr,zgr);
S = shaperead(filename);
hold on;
pcolor3(X,Y,Z,data); # show the 3d matrix
mapshow(S,'FaceColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5]); # show the base map
hold off;
```

I'm not sure if the problem is in function `mapshow`. When I use `mapshow` in a 3d scatterplot, it is good. However, this time, it's bad.

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: the base map is 2d. is it just supposed to be rendered in a plane?

Comment: Yes. I hope to make it on z-plane.